# UnmarshalException while using JAXB

Tags: xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am trying to run this code:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Tags tags = (Tags) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("Tags.xml"));
```

However, I get this error:

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"tags"). Expected elements are (none)

How can I prevent this exception from occuring? This is my root element:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "tags")
```

Comment: Did you generate your model from an XML Schema?

Comment: I am naive in this and I followed this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4J_ytgQ96Kg and did whatever it had

Answer (score 1):

JAXB doesn't know which classes should process.

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Tags.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Tags tags = (Tags) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("Tags.xml"));
```